# Sendgrid free plan limited to 100 emails per day or month?

Tags: sendgrid

I'm using Sendgrid's free plan and it clearly states on their website that the limit is 100 daily; not monthly, yet I get capped at 100 for the entire month.

I read [elsewhere](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135907/why-is-sendgrid-limiting-my-account-to-100-emails-per-month-instead-of-100-email) that I needed to go to **Settings > Account Details > Your Products > Start Trial** to Send More, but I can't seem to find the "Start trial" option under the "Your Products" tab, or anywhere else for that matter.

Am I blind?

Answer (score 1):

The Free Email API plan is 100/day. If you believe you are being incorrectly capped at 100/month, I'd reach out to their [support team](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) so they can check your account for limit accuracy and check sending volumes to confirm or troubleshoot the issue.